# Can someone help me with information on facebook blocking?

Tags: facebook

If I'm friends with someone..let's say my mom, and one of my friends has her blocked, will my mom be able to see what I post to their timeline at all?

Answer (score -1):

You have to post on facebook using **custom** privacy settings by clicking on the icon present in the post bar.

You don't need to block anyone just post using custom privacy settings for whom you want to show posts.